# install mysql linux-image-generic

Tags: mysql, linux, linux-kernel

when i install mysql in ubuntu16.04 kernel is 4.8.0  the system want remove two kernel 4.10.0-38 and 4.10.0-40

terminal source code is

```html
 sudo apt install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libevent-core-2.0-5 libhtml-template-perl mysql-client-5.7
  mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
Suggested packages:
  libipc-sharedcache-perl mailx tinyca
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-38-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libevent-core-2.0-5 libhtml-template-perl mysql-client-5.7
  mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.7
  mysql-server-core-5.7
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 2 to remove and 257 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 18.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 151 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-common all 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [15.6 kB]
Get:2 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libaio1 amd64 0.3.110-2 [6,356 B]
Get:3 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-client-core-5.7 amd64 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [6,339 kB]
Get:4 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-client-5.7 amd64 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [1,675 kB]
Get:5 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-server-core-5.7 amd64 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [7,670 kB]
Get:6 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libevent-core-2.0-5 amd64 2.0.21-stable-2ubuntu0.16.04.1 [70.6 kB]
Get:7 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-server-5.7 amd64 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [2,708 kB]
Get:8 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libhtml-template-perl all 2.95-2 [60.4 kB]
Get:9 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-server all 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [10.2 kB]
Fetched 18.6 MB in 17s (1,051 kB/s)                                            
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 282402 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.10.0-38-generic (4.10.0-38.42~16.04.1) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.10.0-38-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.10.0-38-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-38-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.10.0-38-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-38-generic
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.10.0-38-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.10.0-38-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.10.0-38-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-38-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-38-generic
cp: error reading '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so': Input/output error
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-38-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.10.0-38-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic (4.10.0-42.46~16.04.1) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.10.0-42-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.10.0-42-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-42-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.10.0-42-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-42-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.10.0-42-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-42-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-42-generic
cp: error reading '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so': Input/output error
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-42-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.10.0-38-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

as we see ,the system want remove two kernel when i install mysql-server ,but the progress is wrong.
if someone suffer this problem and know how to solve this question

Comment: This looks like your hard disk is slightly malfunctioning.  Sometimes this can be resolved by rebooting, but in either case run some tests on your HDD

Comment: as other word, file system was breaken ? what should i do for the test ?

Comment: Probably not the file system is broken (thogh this would look similar), but the disk itself.  However, just search for S.M.A.R.T. tools for example